# Chaining pointcuts on same method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have this scenario

```
public List<Object> buildList( Context ctx){
    List objList = new ArrayList();
    //process for objList
    return 
}
```

In the Aspect I have like this

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.personal.service.ProcessList.buildList(..))")
public void interceptor1() {
    //pointcut identifier
}

/**
 * 
 * @param proceedingJoinPoint
 * @return
 */
@Around("interceptor1()")
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint){
    Object[] arguments = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
    Context context = (Context) arguments[1];
    try {
        returnObj = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (context.equals("STANDARD"){
        return standardList( (buildList)returnObj,context);
    }
    else if (context.equals("PRIVELEGE") {
        return privList( (buildList)returnObj,context);
    }
}
```

I would love to have two separate interceptor for STANDARD-- standardInterceptor and PRIVELEGE privelegeInterceptor instead of having an if else condition. Is this possible? 
How to define the pointcut to run the standard  interceptor first and then the privelege interceptor next and then give the response.

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks a bit strange. Firstly, why do you use `getArgs()` instead of binding the intercepted method's first parameter to a `Context` parameter via `args()` in the pointcut? It would be type-safe. Secondly, have you really defined `Context.equals()` method in a way which returns `true` for a `String` comparison? Thirdly, do you really use lower-case class names like `buildList`? And last but not least, if you know that you can cast the return value to `buildList`, why do you not define a `returnObj` of type `buildList` or - even better - limit the pointcut's return type accordingly?

Comment: @kriegaex  I will try the getArgs and the third point about the point cuts return type.  I need to understand what you are trying to say.. will read up. buildList is a method. ProcessList is the class.  Actually context.equals is comparing a enum and not a string , i just modified for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Your code does not make sense, please update it. `(buildList)returnObj` looks like a type cast. Do you mean `buildList(returnObj)`? But the signature `buildList(Context ctx)` implies that `returnObj` must be of type `Context`. Is that so? I would appreciate a more coherent code sample showing what `standardList` and `privList` do, what `returnObj` is and what kind of method you are trying to capture. Otherwise it is hard to answer your question. Anyway, back to your original question: What is the problem with the if-else? Why do you want to avoid it?